# An exchangeable version of the Indian Buffet Process

Tags: stochastic-processes

**Indian Buffet Process**:

In the mathematical theory of probability, the Indian buffet process (IBP) is a stochastic process defining a probability distribution over sparse binary matrices with a finite number of rows and an infinite number of columns. ([More on this process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_buffet_process))

**Question**:

Consider an Indian Buffet Process (IBP) with parameter $\alpha$.

a) The primary definition of IBP is non-exchangeable. Explain the method that makes this process exchangeable.

b) Proof following properties:

- Adopting the above method makes the process exchangeable.
- Number of ones in each row follows $Poisson(\alpha)$.
- Expected total number of ones is $\alpha N$

What I've found so far:

According to the search results, the answer to all of these questions is written in the paper titled "[Infinite Latent Feature Models and the Indian Buffet Process](https://cocosci.princeton.edu/tom/papers/ibptr.pdf)" by Griffiths and Ghahramani. However, I am not knowledgeable enough to understand what the paper says. I want someone to explain the answers. I have searched a lot but no explanation was provided anywhere! Everyone just cites the paper without any discussion. I would be very glad if someone provided something easier to understand as an answer to these questions.